# A question on simply connected domains $U,V \subset \mathbb{C}$, not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and conformal mappings $f:U \rightarrow V$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm given simply connected domains $U,V \subset \mathbb{C}$, not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. Fixing points $a \in U,\ b \in V$. I have to show that $|f'(a)|$ is the same for all conformal mappings $f:U \rightarrow V$ such that $f(a) = b$

Now, by Riemann Mapping Theorem we have $U,V \cong D$, where $D$ is the open disk. via the Riemann maps $g$ and $h$, such that $g(a) = 0$ and $h(b) = 0$, alongwith $g'(a),\ h'(b) >0$

So, we get $k=h \circ f \circ g^{-1}:D \rightarrow D$, with $k(0)=0$. We can now apply Schwarz Lemma on this map, to obtain the condition $|k'(0)|\leq1$. Now, since $l = k^{-1}$, also satisfies the conditions of Schwarz Lemma, we get $|l'(0)|\leq 1 \implies |k'(0)|\geq 1 \implies |k'(0)|=1$.

Therefore, $|h'(b)|\cdot|f'(a)|\cdot1/|g'(a)| = 1 \implies f'(a) = |g'(a)/h'(b)|$

Am I right? Or am I going terribly wrong somewhere? If so, could anyone point me towards the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, except in the last sentence of the third paragraph: $k'(0)=1$ should be $|k'(0)|=1$.

Comment: Corrected, thanks!